# set the font of xlabel to be Arial in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am wondering how to set the font of `xlabel` to be Arial using `matplotlib`. I checked functions like `Axes.set_xlabel` but does not see options to change that.

Comment: We're open to suggestions on how to improve the [fonts_demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/fonts_demo_kw.html) example or similar examples. So if you can tell in how far it does not help...

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The fonts demo doesn't show that you can use the `family` argument to give a font name.  I also noticed that the `fontdict` argument isn't documented for the `set_xlabel` and `set_ylabel` functions.  I'd really like to help improve the docs, what's the best way to begin?

Comment: This is mostly documented in the [development guide](https://matplotlib.org/devel/index.html). You would submit a pull request of the desired change as described in that article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Axes.set_xlabel` and pyplot's `xlabel` functions can take the same keyword arguments as the [`Text` class](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text).  This is noted in the documentation in the *Other Parameters* section.

One of these arguments is `family`, which can be used to set the font by family ('serif', 'sans-serif', etc., as shown in the [font demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/fonts_demo_kw.html)) or by **font name**.  In your case it could be as simple as

```
plt.xlabel('My Label', family='Arial')
```

or

```
ax.set_xlabel('My Label', family='Arial')
# Assuming ax is an instance of Axes.
```